# How Do I Disable the Default Ctrl + V on Datagridview which Pastes Data in c# windows Form?

Tags: c#, datagridview, shortcut, paste

So I have this Win Form Application in which I have a DataGridView.
I have a column which is read only but if I paste data using Ctrl + V into the readonly cell, the data gets pasted.
I want to disable this default keyboard shortcut that comes with the datagridview.
Any help will be deeply appreciated.

```
//dgSBA is the datagridview name 

private void dgSBA_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (!(dgSBA.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == colTask1 | dgSBA.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == colTask2
            | dgSBA.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == colTask3 | dgSBA.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == colTask4
            | dgSBA.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == colExam))
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == (Keys.Control | Keys.V))
            {
                e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
            }
            //Clipboard.Clear();
            dgSBA.ClipboardCopyMode = DataGridViewClipboardCopyMode.Disable;  
        }
        else dgSBA.ClipboardCopyMode = DataGridViewClipboardCopyMode.EnableWithAutoHeaderText;
    }
    #region Catch Exception
    catch (Exception e1)
    { 
        //MessageBox.Show(e1.Message);
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Setting ClipboardCopyMode should be sufficient. Do you mean with "readonly cell" you have a cell editor open but in some kind of readonly state? In that case its a problem of that editor not of the grid.

Comment: Some of my columns have their readonly mode set to false. so a user can copy from there. If the user pastes using keyboard shortcut into a readonly column the data gets pasted. Which I don't want to happen.

Comment: Sound like you have an editor involved then. In that case you might want to register to the EditingControlShowing Event. In that event you can get the editor from the eventargs that will be shown for the cell and change its behavior. It will be different for different controls. For a textbox you might want to disable the paste shortcut via keydown event, the context menu having the paste option and maybe a few other things to prevent pasting.